# Bug! Unordered answer list while clicking on answers link from the profile.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image]

Comment: I don't understant -- can you please say what you were expecting? If you're referring to the fact that your answer is on top, even though Joe's was posted earlier: That's by design. Answers with equal votes are sorted randomly in the default view. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/what-has-happened-to-the-sorting-of-answers-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Answers with equal votes are sorted randomly in the default view.